# Basic Analysis Jiri Lebl Exercises 1.1.6 and 1.1.12

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Firstly, I realise that my question has already been answered a few times, however I just wanted to verify the proof that I came up with for Exercise 1.1.6 in Lebl's Basic Analysis I:

Let $S$ be an ordered set and $A \subset S$ be non-empty and bounded above. Suppose that $\sup A \notin A$. Show that $A$ contains a countably infinite subset.

What I have so far for a proof is:

Consider some $a_1 \in A$, then we know by the definition of the supremum, that $a_1 < \sup A$. Now pick some arbitrary $a_2 \in A$ where $a_1 < a_2$. We then know again by the definition of supremum that $a_1 < a_2 < \sup A$. Inductively, assume that $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \in A$ with $a_1 < a_2 \cdots < a_n < \sup A$. By the definition of the supremum, we then pick an $a_{n+1} \in A$ such that $a_n < a_{n+1}$, meaning it follows that $a_{n+1} < \sup A$ by the supremum definition. Thus $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_n < a_{n+1} < \sup A$. Therefore we can define an infinite set $B = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n, ...\}$, clearly since we were able to assign a natural number to each element of $B$, we know that $|B| = |\mathbb{N}|$, in other words $B \subset A$ is countably infinite.

Furthermore, is it valid to use this result to prove the result in Exercise 1.1.12 which asks for me to prove that every ordered field has a countably infinite subset? My logic is if I assume $F$ is an ordered field and let $A = \{ x \in F \ |\ x < a \}$, then I can use the result from 1.1.6 to show that $A$ has a countably infinite subset which is thus also a subset of $F$.

Comment: Hi, I'm also working on Section 1.1 (Basic properties) exercises. Your proof for exercise 1.1.6 looks fine to me, but have you got any confirmation from a teacher or any other sources? Could you also share the links to the other answers to the exercises? (Sorry I haven't worked on 1.1.12 yet so I can't comment about it.)

Comment: After thinking about it, I think your proof for 1.1.6 has one gap to close: Because you constructed B by infinitely selecting an element on the right side (i.e., the greater side) of $a_1$, it'd be better to prove that there are infinite elements to pick, i.e., $\forall x \in A, \exists y \in A. (x \ne y \land x < y < sup A)$. This can be easily proven by contradiction. With this gap closed, your proof looks good to me.